# insert date data into access database using php?

Tags: php, ms-access

I am trying to insert data to access database but I am having a problem. I know the problem is when I am inserting value **date** because i tried to put NULL there and it worked and inserted everything except the date. I also tried to put date in a string 'date' to take is as a string but it didnt work. Any idea?

```
$query_insert = "insert into orders (Ord_Date, Cus_Id_Fk, Book_Id_Fk) Values ($date,$cus_id, $book_id)";
$insert = odbc_exec($conn, $query_insert) or die (odbc_errormsg());
```

As I said this one with NULL worked, but I need also the date to be inserted.

```
$query_insert = "insert into orders (Ord_Date, Cus_Id_Fk, Book_Id_Fk) Values (null, $cus_id, $book_id)";
$insert = odbc_exec($conn, $query_insert) or die (odbc_errormsg());
```

Comment: What is the format / type of the date field?  `DATE`, `DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP`, `INT`, etc?

Comment: What does your `$date` variable look like?  Is it in YYYY-MM-DD format?

Answer (score 1):

Since your date format is `MM-DD-YYYY`, you have to prepare the $date to fits that format. Here is how

```
$date = date("d-m-Y");
$query_insert = 'INSERT INTO .... ';
```

Comment: @Illyricum, In case you didn't know. Once an answer work, you have to accept that answer as the working answer. Click on the (tick) icon on the left of answer.

Answer (score 0):

1.) manage date format string in mm/dd/yy
2.) encode it with single quote

```
$query_insert = "insert into orders (Ord_Date, Cus_Id_Fk, Book_Id_Fk) Values ('$date',$cus_id, $book_id)";
```

Comment: if your read my question I mentioned that i used single quotes but it doesnt work!!

Comment: what's the error message being displayed? next try alternative enclosing it with #date#

Comment: Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression.                                                          I also tried with # #, no success.

Answer (score 0):

**1st method :**

try

```
SELECT Date();
```

in your access database and get the date format. Then format your date according to that format and use it in your SQL.

**2nd method :**

convert your date to timestamp with PHP, then save it like this:

INSERT INTO TABLE (date_column) values (DateValue(timestamp))